# How can we calculate the maximum height of a fountain?

Tags: aerodynamics

There are two limiters in this question.
First is drag of air.
Second is the viscous forces of pipe.(belong to the tube where water hitts up)
The question is how can we calculate the maximum height with the effect of these two parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's two ways to answer this. The first way is the intellectually precise way, modeling the pump, the water traveling through the pipe and nozzle, the dispersion of the water as it rises influenced by air and surface tension, the air drag on each blob of water as the column separates, the impacts of the falling water on the still-rising column, etc. etc. etc.

The second way is the pragmatic way: use a rule of thumb to choose a pump size and thus water volume per second, divide by the nozzle area to figure out the initial velocity upwards, calculate the height the water would rise to given no air drag nor interference from falling water, and then reduce by some inefficiency parameter (e.g. a ratio of 0.7). Then build the fountain, measure how far off you were, and adjust your rules of thumb for the next time.